# Edit Tomcat configs for Java Web App

Tags: java, tomcat

I managed to make my app run in tomcat on a **Docker Container** but now I'm getting:

> 403 Access Denied You are not authorized to view this page.

My question is how do I access tomcat files like `context.xml` ?? I can't ssh to the container.

Where do I change this files? I'm running it on windows.

Comment: that's perfectly normal that you cannot access or even view such files as there are quite sensitive (context.xml typically contains sensitive information such as access to a database).

Comment: I mean. I can't access my own page. I need to edit permissions in `conf/tomcat-users.xml` but how do I access it??

Comment: Didn't you build the Docker container yourself from files you prepared yourself? If so, then look at the files you used to build the container... that's where you change the file, then re-deploy the (Docker) container.